# Create keyframes from selected objects in Flash

Tags: flash, jsfl

I have let's say 40 bitmap images and i want to create a frame by frame animation from them. Is there a way to do it automatically, instead of moving the keyframes one by one. There is only an option: Distribute to layers. I'm looking for something like: `Distribute to keyframes`.

I'm using Flash CS6. I don't think flash supports this kind of operation, but maybe some jsfl script?

Answer (score 1):

**Downloading an image sequence on your timeline**

If you want to create a MovieClip with your 40 Bitmaps. Put all your images into a folder (named pic001, pic002, pic003...). Open a new Flash file. Go to "File" > "import" > "import in the scene". Click on the first image of your folder, select "open". A window appears asking you if you want to import all the files: choose "yes". All your images are now aligned one after the other in your timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I found a helpful solution.
The ItemsToFrames script does something similar and was very useful for me.

http://robotacid.com/documents/jsfl/index.html